# Add checkbox form input to backend Wordpress user information

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

So I’m trying to create a custom registration page for my Wordpress website and found a tutorial on how to add custom fields. I figured out how to make the entire form work correctly, I added an full name, last name and age field. I just can’t figure out how to make the checkbox input display in the backend for the position.

So the form goes like this, you can view it at [team.ifatceg.com](https://team.ifatceg.com/login/?action=register).

The position is the one I can’t figure out how to display it in the backend. The rest I can.

Here’s two pictures depicting the form and what is shown in the user’s page in the backend. The issue being that what they selected in the checkbox is not being displayed on the user’s page in the backend.

https://ibb.co/4PnRns3
https://ibb.co/hgZPz0r

Here is the plugin:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Registration Fields
Plugin URI:
Description:
Version: 0.1
Author: CSSIgniter
Author URI:
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/


/**
 * Front end registration
 */

add_action( 'register_form', 'crf_registration_form' );
function crf_registration_form() {

$first_name = ! empty( $_POST['first_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Name', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="text"
            id="first_name"
            name="first_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $first_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
            />
        </label>
    </p>
     <?php

$last_name = ! empty( $_POST['last_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last Name', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="text"
            id="last_name"
            name="last_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $last_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
            />
        </label>
     <?php

$age = ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ? intval( $_POST['age'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="number"
                   min="16"
                   max="100"
                   step="1"
                   id="age"
                   name="age"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $age ); ?>"
                   class="input"
            />
        </label>
        <?php

$position = ! empty( $_POST['position '] ) ? intval( $_POST['position'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'What position are you applying for?', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
<small>The writing and moderation team is invite only so all applicants who choose those options and have not been invited will be ignored.</small><br><br>

<form action="third.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="writer" id="position" value="writer">
    <label for="writer">Writing</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="writer" id="position" value="video">
    <label for="video">Video Editor</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mod" id="position" value="moderator">
    <label for="moderator">Moderator</label><br>
</p>
<br><br>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'crf_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name', __( 'Please enter your first name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

     if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name', __( 'Please enter your last name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'Please enter your age.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) && intval( $_POST['age'] ) < 16 ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'You must be 16 years of age or older to apply.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'crf_user_register' );
function crf_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }

     if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
    }
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'age', intval( $_POST['age'] ) );
    }
     if ( ! empty( $_POST['position'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'position', intval( $_POST['position'] ) );
    }
}
/**
 * Back end registration
 */

add_action( 'user_new_form', 'crf_admin_registration_form' );
function crf_admin_registration_form( $operation ) {
    if ( 'add-new-user' !== $operation ) {
        // $operation may also be 'add-existing-user'
        return;
    }

$first_name = ! empty( $_POST['first_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

$last_name = ! empty( $_POST['last_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

$age = ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ? intval( $_POST['age'] ) : ''; 

$position = ! empty( $_POST['position '] ) ? intval( $_POST['position'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr> 
           <th><label for="first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Name', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"
                 id="first_name"
            name="first_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $first_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
                  />
            </td>

<th><label for="last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last Name', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"
                 id="last_name"
            name="last_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $last_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
                  />
            </td>

            <th><label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="number"
                   min="16"
                   max="100"
                   step="1"
                   id="age"
                   name="age"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $age ); ?>"
                   class="input"
            />
            </td>

            <th><label for="position"><?php esc_html_e( 'Position', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="position1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $writer ); ?>">
  <label for="position1">Writing</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="position2" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $video ); ?>">
  <label for="position2">Video Editing</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="position3" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $moderator ); ?>">
  <label for="position3">Moderator</label>
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'crf_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_user_profile_update_errors( $errors, $update, $user ) {
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name', __( 'Please enter your first name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

     if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name', __( 'Please enter your last name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'Please enter your age.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) && intval( $_POST['age'] ) < 16 ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'You must be 16 years of age or older to apply.', 'crf' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'crf_user_register' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Application Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
                  <th><label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'age', $user->ID ) ); ?></td>
                <th><label for="position"><?php esc_html_e( 'Position', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'position', $user->ID ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say you can't get it to display in the back end, do you mean you cant see what position the user applied for? or you have a separate form that you control on the back end and assign a position to a user and you can't get that to work?

Comment: I updated my main post, thanks for that question. Meaning there’s the form to register in the front end. Then in the Users information I have a field that displays what they input when the registered. 

https://ibb.co/4PnRns3
https://ibb.co/hgZPz0r

Comment: Got it, did you confirm that their data is being stored in the database for the position section?

Comment: I think I know where to check but also have no idea, where would I look?

Comment: phpmyadmin, find your db and open up the usermeta table and look for the 'position' in there somewhere and let me know what its being stored as.

Comment: Ok, I checked. There is nothing in the usermeta table for anything relating to any of the custom fields I added. Neither the “Age” or “Position” are in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use the multiple choice question, I switched it to a single checkbox.

`<input type="checkbox" name="writer" value="Yes" />`

Works now! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I rewrote a lot of code for you.  Try this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Registration Fields
Plugin URI:
Description:
Version: 0.1
Author: CSSIgniter
Author URI:
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/


/**
 * Front end registration
 */

add_action( 'register_form', 'crf_registration_form' );
function crf_registration_form() {

$first_name = ! empty( $_POST['first_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Name', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="text"
            id="first_name"
            name="first_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $first_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
            />
        </label>
    </p>
     <?php

$last_name = ! empty( $_POST['last_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last Name', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="text"
            id="last_name"
            name="last_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $last_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
            />
        </label>
     <?php

$age = ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ? intval( $_POST['age'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="number"
                   min="16"
                   max="100"
                   step="1"
                   id="age"
                   name="age"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $age ); ?>"
                   class="input"
            />
        </label>
        <?php

$position = ! empty( $_POST['position '] ) ? intval( $_POST['position'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'What position are you applying for?', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
<small>The writing and moderation team is invite only so all applicants who choose those options and have not been invited will be ignored.</small><br><br>

<form action="third.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="writer" id="position" value="writer">
    <label for="writer">Writing</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="video" id="position" value="video">
    <label for="video">Video Editor</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mod" id="position" value="moderator">
    <label for="moderator">Moderator</label><br>
</p>
<br><br>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'crf_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name', __( 'Please enter your first name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

     if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name', __( 'Please enter your last name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'Please enter your age.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) && intval( $_POST['age'] ) < 16 ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'You must be 16 years of age or older to apply.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'crf_user_register' );
function crf_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }

     if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
    }
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'age', intval( $_POST['age'] ) );
    }
     if ( ! empty( $_POST['position'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'position', intval( $_POST['position'] ) );
    }
    If( isset($_POST['writer']) ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'writer', true);
    }
        If( isset($_POST['video']) ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'video', true);
    }
        If( isset($_POST['mod']) ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mod', true);
    }

}
/**
 * Back end registration
 */

add_action( 'user_new_form', 'crf_admin_registration_form' );
function crf_admin_registration_form( $operation ) {
    if ( 'add-new-user' !== $operation ) {
        // $operation may also be 'add-existing-user'
        return;
    }

$first_name = ! empty( $_POST['first_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

$last_name = ! empty( $_POST['last_name '] ) ? intval( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

$age = ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ? intval( $_POST['age'] ) : ''; 

$position = ! empty( $_POST['position '] ) ? intval( $_POST['position'] ) : '';
$writer = ! empty( $_POST['writer '] ) ? intval( $_POST['writer'] ) : '';
$video = ! empty( $_POST['video '] ) ? intval( $_POST['video'] ) : '';
$mod = ! empty( $_POST['mod '] ) ? intval( $_POST['mod'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr> 
           <th><label for="first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Name', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"
                 id="first_name"
            name="first_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $first_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
                  />
            </td>

<th><label for="last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last Name', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"
                 id="last_name"
            name="last_name"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $last_name ); ?>"
            class="input"
                  />
            </td>

            <th><label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input type="number"
                   min="16"
                   max="100"
                   step="1"
                   id="age"
                   name="age"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $age ); ?>"
                   class="input"
            />
            </td>

            <th><label for="position"><?php esc_html_e( 'Position', 'crf' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'crf' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="position1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $writer ); ?>">
  <label for="position1">Writing</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="position2" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $video ); ?>">
  <label for="position2">Video Editing</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="position3" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $mod ); ?>">
  <label for="position3">Moderator</label>
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'crf_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_user_profile_update_errors( $errors, $update, $user ) {
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name', __( 'Please enter your first name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

     if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name', __( 'Please enter your last name.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'Please enter your age.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) && intval( $_POST['age'] ) < 16 ) {
        $errors->add( 'age', __( 'You must be 16 years of age or older to apply.', 'crf' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'crf_user_register' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Application Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
                  <th><label for="age"><?php esc_html_e( 'Age', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'age', $user->ID ) ); ?></td>
                <th><label for="video"><?php esc_html_e( 'Video', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'video', $user->ID ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That did not work but thank you for editing. I may have figured out how to fix it using yours though.

Comment: No problem, hope you figure it out.